# PHP Session Class and $_SESSION Array

Tags: php, oop, session

i've implemented this custom PHP Session Class for storing sessions into a MySQL database:

```
class Session
{
    private $_session;
    public $maxTime;
    private $database;
    public function __construct(mysqli $database)
    {
        $this->database=$database;
        $this->maxTime['access'] = time();
        $this->maxTime['gc'] = get_cfg_var('session.gc_maxlifetime');

        session_set_save_handler(array($this,'_open'),
                array($this,'_close'),
                array($this,'_read'),
                array($this,'_write'),
                array($this,'_destroy'),
                array($this,'_clean')
                );

        register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

        session_start();//SESSION START

    }

    public function _open()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function _close()
    {
        $this->_clean($this->maxTime['gc']);
    }

    public function _read($id)
    {
        $getData= $this->database->prepare("SELECT data FROM 
                                            Sessions AS Session
                                            WHERE Session.id = ?");
        $getData->bind_param('s',$id);
        $getData->execute();

        $allData= $getData->fetch();
        $totalData = count($allData);
        $hasData=(bool) $totalData >=1;

        return $hasData ? $allData['data'] : '';
    }

    public function _write($id, $data)
    {
        $getData = $this->database->prepare("REPLACE INTO
            Sessions
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $getData->bind_param('sss', $id, $this->maxTime['access'], $data);

        return $getData->execute();
    }

    public function _destroy($id)
    {
        $getData=$this->database->prepare("DELETE FROM
            Sessions
            WHERE id = ?");
        $getData->bind_param('S', $id);
        return $getData->execute();
    }

    public function _clean($max)
    {
        $old=($this->maxTime['access'] - $max);

        $getData = $this->database->prepare("DELETE FROM Sessions WHERE access < ?");
        $getData->bind_param('s', $old);
        return $getData->execute();
    }
}
```

It works well but i don't really know how to properly access the `$_SESSION` array:
For example:

```
$db=new DBClass();//This is a custom database class
$session=new Session($db->getConnection());
if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    echo($_SESSION['user']);//THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED!
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['user']="test";
    Echo("Session created!");
}
```

At every page refresh it seems that `$_SESSION['user']` is somehow "resetted", what methods can i apply to prevent such behaviour?

Comment: Am I the only one who sees the random 'not' in the tags? Why is it there?

Comment: There's no error handling code in case a query/prepare/execute() fails. YOu might want to add that.

Comment: @Carson Myers: No, I see it too. That's really strange.

Comment: There was a minus before the "sessions" tag, i edited it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt::fetch()` doesn't return an array representing the row, it only returns true or false. Therefore your code in `_read()`

```
$allData= $getData->fetch();
$totalData = count($allData);
$hasData=(bool) $totalData >=1;
return $hasData ? $allData['data'] : '';
```

cannot work. `$allData` will either be `true` or `false` and there is no array element `$allData['data']`.

http://docs.php.net/mysqli-stmt.fetch says:

> Fetch the result from a prepared statement into the variables bound by [mysqli_stmt_bind_result()](http://docs.php.net/mysqli_stmt_bind_result).

```
  public function _read($id)
  {
    $getData= $this->database->prepare("SELECT data FROM
      Sessions AS Session
      WHERE Session.id = ?
    ");
    if ( false===$getData ) {
      // now what?
    }

    $getData->bind_param('s',$id);
    $getData->bind_result($data);
    if ( false===$getData->execute() ) {
      // now what?
    }
    return  $getData->fetch() ? $data : '';
  }
```

Comment: Guess i should read more carefully PHP Doc in the future...thanks again everybody!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the updated code!!! :-)
Now it's fully working!!!

```
<?php
class session {
    private $_session;
    public $maxTime;
    private $db;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->maxTime['access'] = time();
        $this->maxTime['gc'] = 21600; //21600 = 6 hours

        //it is session handler
        session_set_save_handler(array($this,'_open'),
                array($this,'_close'),
                array($this,'_read'),
                array($this,'_write'),
                array($this,'_destroy'),
                array($this,'_clean')
                );

        register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

        session_start();//SESSION START
    }

    private function getDB() {
        $mysql_host = 'your_host';
        $mysql_user = 'user';
        $mysql_password = 'pass';
        $mysql_db_name = 'db_name';


        if (!isset($this->db)) {
            $this->db = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_db_name);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Error no connection: <br />%s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }
        }

        return $this->db;
    }

    // O_O !!!
    public function _open() {
        return true;
    }


    public function _close() {
        $this->_clean($this->maxTime['gc']);
    }

    public function _read($id)  {       
        $stmt= $this->getDB()->prepare("SELECT session_variable FROM table_sessions 
                                            WHERE table_sessions.session_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$id);
        $stmt->bind_result($data);
        $stmt->execute();
        $ok = $stmt->fetch() ? $data : '';
        $stmt->close();
        return $ok;
    }

    public function _write($id, $data) {    
        $stmt = $this->getDB()->prepare("REPLACE INTO table_sessions (session_id, session_variable, session_access) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $id, $data, $this->maxTime['access']);
        $ok = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        return $ok;     
    }

    public function _destroy($id) {
    $stmt=$this->getDB()->prepare("DELETE FROM table_sessions WHERE session_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $ok = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    return $ok;
    }

    public function _clean($max) {
    $old=($this->maxTime['access'] - $max);
    $stmt = $this->getDB()->prepare("DELETE FROM table_sessions WHERE session_access < ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $old);
    $ok = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    return $ok;
    }
}
?>
```

Here's the session table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `session_variable` text NOT NULL,
  `session_access` decimal(15,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Thanks, now people can use it properly ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to [start a session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) first?

Comment: session_start() is being called in the Constructor of the Session class.

As long as he creates an instance of the Session class first, shouldn't this be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I have had it before where sessions don't seem to persist as they should

You could try checking your sessionid stays the same when you change page and if not set it manually.

```
var_dump(session_id());

if (session_id()=="")
{
    if ($_GET["sessionid"])
    {
        session_id($_GET["sessionid"]);
    }
    elseif ($_POST["sessionid"])
    {
        session_id($_POST["sessionid"]);
    }

    session_start();
}
```

This is more of a test to see if this is the problem tho.  I'm not sure what the security implications would be of setting the session id from the query string but I suspect they are not good!

Comment: Yes, the sessionid stay the same after every page refresh...i wonder if creating a new Session Object at every refresh IS the actual problem (the Constructor calls session_start() everytime)...!